# In Selenium Webdriver what do you usel for test case document?

Tags: selenium, frameworks, webdriver

What is advisable and appropriate according to you?
Do you use Excel document for test case document?
Do you parameterize directly from your test data directly from Test Case Document?
Do you have separate Excel file for Test Data?
Do you use Database for test data data parameterization?
Do you use XML file for test data parameterization?

What is the right way? Which way fits the best in which condition?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Clarify your question. What do you want?

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Can you tell me if you use the excel for Test case document, so that you can parameterize directly from Test Case Document? And if you do so what all issues or impediments can be faced?

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong way for test data parameterization. You can use excel, db, xml, json, txt files etc.

There would be enough examples on how to use any of these, so online support wise all are ok.

Regarding usage, if the testing team itself prepares the data and the testing team has good technical knowledge with json, xml etc, then these options can be used.

There have been instances where test data is provided by different teams. This can be BAs, or multiple teams working together (in case of enterprise E2E applications). In such scenarios, maintaining data in excel can be useful. Excel also provides better visualization of data.

If you use git or something for version control, then excel might be a problem as you might not see what exact data has changed.

Using DB for data setup would seem like an overkill in a lot of scenarios.